# PHPUnit test files using prefix

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I need to test all classes in a range of subfolders. However, I do not want to test the other files in these subfolders until I have done a large refactoring.

The files I want to test all start with `class.`, e.g. `class.apis.php`, `class.something.php`.

So, in order to run my tests I have the folloring configuration for PHPUnit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="true" backupStaticAttributes="true" colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true" convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="false" syntaxCheck="true" verbose="true"
    strict="true">
    <php>
        <includePath>../</includePath>
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="MSBO Test Suite">
            <directory>PHPUnit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">../classes/</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../modules/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../classes/external/</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

But I cannot find anything on how to add a prefix to the whitelisting. Any ideas?

Comment: @lkessler - Please don't use comments for this. These are off topic and being flagged all over the site. I'll remove the others.

Comment: What about <directory prefix="class." suffix=".php"> ? ^^'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use different extensions, instead of a prefix, so we have:

```
<directory suffix=".class">lib/UTIL</directory>
```

You might be able to use a wild card in the file name filter, although I have not tried this.

```
<file>lib/UTIL/AJAX*.class</file>
```

Comment: Any chance to rename from a prefix to a suffix?  If not, maybe add a request to the bug list of PHPUnit for prefix support?

Comment: if there is no other solution, then yes... i guess it should be done that way.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old thread, but just to complement the previous responses. This feature was added for PHPUnit 6.5.10. You can check the related updates at:

- https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3218
- https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/2d53bd5ae8ec6f81bb3be9d397f1f4cfac69ff97

Also available at `phpunit >v7.2` (tested on `v7.5.17` and worked fine). Not sure on which specific version was added tho.